# Geocoding Result layer does not show up in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, geocoding

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZggh.png

Everything was going fine until I geocoded the addresses. The addresses were all matched, but the Geocoding Result layer wouldn't show itself on the map. There should be about 40 points that are missing.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
I already checked for coordinate systems; they're the same.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GISse!  I think in order to be able to help you more effectively, you need to provide some more explanation of what you are doing, and the steps you have taken so far.  You are geocoding addresses.  What are you using as your geocoding base layer?  What is the base layer you are overlaying the roads and addresses on?  What are the coordinate systems of each?  What is the coordinate system of the data frame?  Geocoding parameters?  It is detail like this that will help other people give you advice or guidance to work toward an answer.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out. Turns out what was wrong was that I didn't read unmatched results = 41, instead of matched results = 41. Hadn't slept in a while, so it'll do that to you.